# How can I create domain - joined account? How to create domain network Windows?

Tags: windows-domain

I have a project for which I need to create a simple program using MS-MPI (Microsoft Message Passing Interface). I am trying to run it using my two PCs at home (both running Windows 10). To do this I connected them through WORKGROUP in my WiFi at home, then I run smpd -d on both computers and tried running the code using both machines. The problem which occurs is that smpd reports that proc id and user id are different.
So on Microsoft support site about MPI I found a thread with similar issue, and it seems that the problem is solved by running the smpd on the same domain-joined account.
However, I have no experience at all with network set ups beyond basic Homegroup and it seems I need to create a domain server and connect both PCs to the domain, and then create user-account for it.
So if anyone could help me and explain how to make this set up solely for the purpose of MPI functioning and using no more than my two Windows 10 PCs at home, it would be a great help.

Comment: You won't be able to. In order to setup a domain you would need to get an Active Directory running which is only available on Windows Server versions. If you elaborated what you're actually trying to do/what errors you're seeing you might be able to get some better help. Also include a reference to the source for your solution, it could help.

Comment: Such question requires so much detailed answer and it could have many scenarios. i posted a small briefing how to get you through that but after that you need to do your own research or post more questions on the forum .

Comment: @Seth here are two screenshots of what I am trying to do and what is the issue PC1 - [link](https://s30.postimg.org/bv03d7vs1/Untitled1.png)  PC2 - [link](https://s28.postimg.org/6bldfpnjh/Untitled.png), ConsoleApplication1 is a very simple program with only a few lines of code just to test the use of both machines in parallel, and how complicated would the set be if got Windows Server OS?

Comment: @Elie Thank you for the briefing, I'll try to get the most out of it, and if I get stuck possibly post a question again

Comment: dont forget to mark the thread as answered if it works for you .

Comment: @Elie I won't it'll just take a bit to set-up everything as you instructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a virtual machine or one of those two machines to create a domain .

First you need to install windows server, in your case 2008 r2 should be sufficient you can of course try 2012 r2 and 2016 but i would still recommend 2008 R2 .

Next step after installing a windows server you need to:

Click Start menu, open Administrative Tools > Server Manager then select roles directory  > roles summary > Add Roles, Follow the steps and when you reach to role selection you should select Active Directory Domain Services check box, and then click Next it will prompt you that it will install additional features like DNS just accept and continue .

After the role is successfully installed you should promote your server as a Domain Controller to do so, open command prompt and type dcpromo and chose advanced mode installation and follow instructions, On the Choose a Deployment Configuration page, select Create a new domain in a new forest and then click Next, then you should give a name to your forest ( domain ) for example :
Test.lab.com

Then Set Forest Functional Level page, select Windows Server 2008 R2, On the Additional Domain Controller Options page, ensure that the DNS server check box is selected, and then click Next, then follow on screen instructions and chose an administrator password.

After you are done i suggest you edit your DNS IP address to be the same as the machine ip ( let say your computer's IP is 192.168.61.2 ) depending on the IP you have .

Upon reboot you will have to switch user to log in to the machine by selecting :

Switch User

and logging in with DOMAIN\Administrator and using the administrator password you created . Example :

Lets say your domain name is Test.lab.com you will enter Test\Administrator .

Then on the other computer you need to right click my computer > Properties > Change settings > To rename this computer or change its domain or workgroup click on change > select domain and type in the fully qualified domain name you chose AKA Test.lab.com . It will ask you for credentials you will provide them as Test\Administrator and your password .

Make sure on the second machine before joining the newly created domain that you have your DNS set as the same as the First PC's which is its IP which is ( 192.168.61.2 ).

I gave you a small briefing about it and the super basics how to get it installed more info and steps could be found [Here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-active-directory-domain-services-on-windows-server-2008-r2-enterprise-64-bit/) but i would still recommend to not go through that step unless you really know what you are getting into and i highly suggest that you would run it on Virtual Machine .

Comment: So I followed almost your entire tutorial and set up everything as Instructed, however now when I try to joing to the domain on other machine I get the message AD DC for the domain "******" could not be contacted. In more detalis it says "DNS name does not exist". So is this the issue with how I set up these DNS IPs, if so could you give me more details how to properly set them?

Comment: Ok so actually now I set up DNS IPs in a way that I get a different message error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Comment: Can you post ipconfig /all on the AD DC and on the client side ? And did you install DNS role on AD DC ? And is firewall off on both machines ?

Comment: Why do you recommend 2008 R2?

Comment: @Seth i recommended windows server 2008 R2 cause he did not specify the computer specification its somehow light for VM and doesnt take much work to configure i also suggested the other OS versions its up for him to decide what is better to chose .

Comment: @Elie So it turned out I acutally mistyped machine's IP address when I copied it to the preferred DNS address. After I corrected this I connected to the domain with other machine without a problem, so your guide was spot on and didn't really need anything beside it. You were a great help, thank you.